# python script to simulate a GET Request + receive the results

Tags: python, bash, get, request

how can i make a script to simulate a GET Request + receive the results
so to send this request but to be able to receive the answer also
in python bash or php, etc

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/2004 1107 Firefox/1.0
Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use curl in bash

```
curl -H "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5" -H "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" ... [url]
```

usefull options:

- --keepalive-time